# Polymer add style dynamically

Tags: styles, polymer

In a polymer control,'my-grid', I'm trying to add style via the below code:

```
var styleElement = document.createElement('style', 'custom-style');
styleElement.innerHTML = cssText;
Polymer.StyleDefaults.addStyle(styleElement);
```

Here, the cssText can be string like

```
.oc-col-id-0{ 
     flex-basis: var(--oc-col-id-0-flex-basis); 
     -webkit-flex-basis: var(--oc-col-id-0-flex-basis);
}  
.oc-col-id-1{
       flex-basis: var(--oc-col-id-1-flex-basis); 
       -webkit-flex-basis: var(--oc-col-id-1-flex-basis);
}
```

Without this custom variables, I can append the styleElement by

```
this.$.gridContainer.appendChild(styleElement);
```

But however, since there are custom variables, I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

After the element is attached, I can't change the --oc-col-id-0-flex-basis value via

```
this.customStyle['--oc-col-id-0-flex-basis'] = maxWidth + "px";
this.updateStyles();
```

It looks that the style variables are not applied to the element.

I'm not sure if there is any way to dynamically add/modify the style of the element. I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: I've updated the post.

Comment: Have you initialized your custom var with some value? If not, can try this after initializing once

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in the end to inject the style class dynamically. It solved my problem so far.

```
            var style = this._styles[0];
            var text = style.textContent;
            var cssText = "";
            for (var id of ids)
            {
                var classStyle = ".col-id-" + id;

                var variableProperty = "--col-id-" + id + "-flex-basis";
                if (text.indexOf(classStyle) == -1)
                {
                    cssText += classStyle + "{ flex-basis: var(" + variableProperty + ", auto); -webkit-flex-basis: var(" + variableProperty + ", auto);} ";
                }

                if (this._ownStylePropertyNames.indexOf(variableProperty) == -1)
                {
                    this._ownStylePropertyNames.push(variableProperty);
                }
            }

            if (cssText.length > 0)
            {
                style.textContent += " " + cssText;
                style.__cssRules = null; //trick for rulesForStyle method in Polymer.html                   
            }
```